# (Julia 1.x) Set value of array index in struct

Tags: struct, julia

A `Dict` containing multiple `Array` values can have its data altered elementwise by iterating over the corresponding keys and the arrays themselves, along the lines of:

```
"""dictdemo.jl"""
tempdict = Dict{String, Any}("a"=>zeros(1),
                             "b"=>zeros(2),
                             "c"=>zeros(3),
                             "x"=>zeros(4),
                             "y"=>zeros(5),
                             "z"=>zeros(6))

for var ∈ ["x", "y", "z"]
    for i in eachindex(tempdict[var])
        tempdict[var][i] = rand()
    end
end

for key in sort(collect(keys(tempdict)))
    println("$key: $(tempdict[key])")
end


$> julia dictdemo.jl
a: [0.0]
b: [0.0, 0.0]
c: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
x: [0.0444697, 0.715464, 0.703251, 0.0739732]
y: [0.168588, 0.548075, 0.923591, 0.124419, 0.753477]
z: [0.481123, 0.976423, 0.00690676, 0.0602968, 0.326228, 0.448793]
```

Akin to this, I have a `struct` which contains multiple fields of type `Array` and am attempting to alter the values within those arrays elementwise for multiple fields at a time. I know of a few methods by which the array values may be set, but they are all limited in either being unable to iterate over multiple fields (`mystruct.field[indices] = value`) or being unable to set individual elements (`setfield!(mystruct, field, value)`, `mystruct.field = value`).

```
"""structdemo.jl"""
mutable struct MyStruct
    a::Array{Float64,1}
    b::Array{Float64,1}
    c::Array{Float64,1}
    x::Array{Float64,1}
    y::Array{Float64,1}
    z::Array{Float64,1}
    MyStruct() = new(zeros(1),
                     zeros(2),
                     zeros(3),
                     zeros(4),
                     zeros(5),
                     zeros(6))
end

tempstruct = MyStruct()

setfield!(tempstruct, Symbol("x"), [rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()])

tempstruct.y = [rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()]

for i in eachindex(tempstruct.z)
    tempstruct.z[i] = rand()
end

for f in fieldnames(typeof(tempstruct))
    println("$f: $(getfield(tempstruct, f))")
end


$> julia structdemo.jl 
a: [0.0]
b: [0.0, 0.0]
c: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
x: [0.222734, 0.796599, 0.565279, 0.0488704]
y: [0.67695, 0.367068, 0.384466, 0.160438, 0.154411]
z: [0.744013, 0.0358193, 0.466726, 0.562945, 0.895279, 0.815217]
```

I am looking to have something of the form (except my values are not set by `rand()`):

```
for var ∈ ["x", "y", "z"]
    for i in eachindex(tempstruct.Symbol(var))
        tempstruct.Symbol(var)[i] = rand()
    end
end
```

My question is then, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getproperty` function like this:

```
for var ∈ ["x", "y", "z"]
    field = getproperty(tempstruct,Symbol(var))
    for i in eachindex(field)
        field[i] = rand()
    end
end
```

You can use `propertynames` function to get a `Tuple` of `Symbol`s that give you a list of names of properties of your struct:

```
julia> propertynames(tempstruct)
(:a, :b, :c, :x, :y, :z)
```

Also note that you could just write `[:x, :y, :z]` instead of `["x", "y", "z"]` and there is no need of `Symbol(var)` conversion.

As an additional information it is good to know that some types override `getpropety` function (e.g. have a look at DataFrames.jl type `DataFrame` structure which does not return its fields via `getproperty` but its columns). In such cases a direct access to **fields** of a `struct` can be gained by the `getfield` function and the `fieldnames` function gives you a list of field names of your type.